# Bring form front of a pop up

Tags: c#-4.0

I m working with C# windows Forms. I have a third party pop up. I want my forms should come on front of that pop up on mouse click. please Help.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Uninstall that third party app.  Nuke from orbit, only way to be sure.  Don't do anything that makes your user uninstall you instead.

Comment: After being patient enough, I have deleted my answer because of not feeling like helping you.

Comment: @ varocarbas, its not compulsion to answer every question. Whenever helping a someone u should always leave ur ego aside